# Rewriting this SQL in Lambda - using count and group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I'm stuck rewriting this SQL in Lambda:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 COUNT(LoginDateTime)
      ,[LoginDateTime]
      ,[Culture]
  FROM [LearningApp].[dbo].[UserActivities]
  group by LoginDateTime, Culture
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|     |      LoginDateTime        |  Culture |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|  1  |  2016-07-14 12:21:23.307  |    de    |
|  4  |  2016-07-13 12:21:23.307  |    en    |
|  2  |  2016-07-14 12:21:23.307  |    en    |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
```

And my code:

```
public List<UserActivityResponseContract> GetUserActivity()
{
    var userActivityResponseContracts = new List<UserActivityResponseContract>();

    var userActivitiesList = _baseCommands.GetAll<UserActivity>()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.LoginDateTime, 
            x.Culture
        })
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.LoginDateTime, x.Culture});

    foreach (var userActivity in userActivitiesList)
    {
        userActivityResponseContracts.Add(new UserActivityResponseContract
        {
            ActivityDate = userActivity.Key.LoginDateTime.ToShortDateString(),
            NumberOfTimesLoggedIn = userActivity.Count(),
            Culture = userActivity.Key.Culture
        });
    }
    return userActivityResponseContracts;
}
```

It doesn't seem very difficult but I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Is that SQL really what you want? It looks like you're grouping by timestamps down to the millisecond, and then setting ActivityDate to only the Date part.

Comment: @Sconibulus I only care about the day part of the date because it's a query where I want to see activity by day.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to select and group by the date, rather than the timestamp. e.g.: SELECT CAST(LoginDateTime AS DATE)

Comment: Otherwise you might (depending on your data) return a dozen different timestamps with different counts for each day/culture pairing.

Answer (score 3):

Method Syntax:

```
var result = _baseCommands.GetAll<UserActivity>()
                          .GroupBy(x => new { x.LoginDateTime, x.Culture})
                          .Select (x => new UserActivityResponseContract
                          { 
                              ActivityDate = x.Key.LoginDateTime.ToShortDateString(),
                              Culture = x.Key.Culture, 
                              NumberOfTimesLoggedIn = x.Count()
                          })
                          .Take(1000).ToList();
```

*You can also use an overload of `GroupBy` that enables you to pass the `select` function  as a second parameter*

Query Syntax:

```
var result = (from x in _baseCommands.GetAll<UserActivity>()
              group x by new { x.LoginDateTime, x.Culture} into g
              select new UserActivityResponseContract
              { 
                 ActivityDate = g.Key.LoginDateTime.ToShortDateString(),
                 Culture = g.Key.Culture, 
                 NumberOfTimesLoggedIn = g.Count()
              }).Take(1000).ToList();
```

---

To `GroupBy` just the `Date` part of this `DateTime` do: `x.LoginDateTime.Date`